# C# Winform: Only partial file write ability

Tags: c#, winforms

I've inherited a C# Winform application that write database information into various file formats (CSV, XML, Excel) according to our clients' needs. I've recently added another format and it works fine in Debug mode. However, when I Publish it, everything else works except for my new addition.

Can someone tell me if there's a setting or something that is preventing my new addition from working in the Published version while working in the Debug version?

Comment: Review its implementation and put log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question, I've published many applications in Debug mode so during some time I can more easily troubleshoot issues by remote debugging, etc..., so no problem with that.

Many times the 'it works in my machine' is a result of clients not having the proper DLL's for your new feature... It happened many times to me, it seems obvious that everything is ok until you take a look into Fusion log files... Activate the fusion logs and add traces

Comment: Given that I'm testing the published program on the same machine as the one it was developed one, I should have the proper DLLs, right?

Comment: I solved it. Though it wasn't a DLL missing, it that answer reminded me of a XML configuration file that seemed to be not getting deployed when I pressed "Publish". It needed to be set as "Include\Required\Include" in the Application Files section of Publish.

Answer (score 1):

By Publish what you mean? if you using VS publish method, then it will not replace the dlls if the version is same.  You need to change the version in AssemblyInfo.cs and then publish again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Visual Studio's Publish method. I've been updating the AssemblyInfo.cs every time to match the "Publish Version" number, but still nothing.